# Custom Exception not caught, but unhandled

Tags: exception, try-catch

I have a custom exception class that inherits Exception.
In my Try-Catch block I have a line of code that causes an InvalidCastException.

But the exception is always unhandled at the code line that caused it and not caught by the Catch block.

```
Public Class InvalidPremiumException
Inherits System.Exception

Public Sub New()

End Sub

Public Sub New(message As String)
    MyBase.New(message)
End Sub

Public Sub New(message As String, inner As Exception)
    MyBase.New(message, inner)
End Sub

End Class
```

Then in another class:

```
Try
' code that causes an InvalidCastException here

Catch ex As InvalidPremiumException
Console.WriteLine("Invalid or Missing Premium")
End Try
```

Comment: If my answer below has resolved your issue, please mark it as 'Answer'

Answer (score 0):

You are catching `InvalidPremiumException` in the `Catch` block. Only that exception will be caught in this block that is of type `InvalidPremiumException` or is inherited from it, others will go unhandled.

You may also consider using multiple `catch` blocks.

The `InvalidCastException` will be handled in the second `Catch` block:

```
Try
    ' code that causes an InvalidCastException here

Catch ex As InvalidPremiumException
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid or Missing Premium")

Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("Catching other exceptions")
End Try
```

The `Catch` block will only handle those exceptions which are either of the same type or one of its children's type. That is why your custom exception is handled in the second block.

Comment: Tell me if I understand the issue correctly. You want to catch the InvalidCastException in your Catch block where you handle InvalidPremiumException?

Comment: Ah - I didn't clock the comment said `InvalidCastException` - @user3231512 is this actual code that's causing the problem?

Comment: What I'm wanting to know is, Why can't you catch an exception (that is defined as a custom exception that derives from Exception), in a Catch block ??

Comment: You can do that but (as I already mentioned) it has to be either the same class or the one inherited from it. One other option can be to add multiple catch blocks.

Comment: I am using the one inherited from it! I'm using InvalidPremiumException Inherits Exception.

Now, Exception is a general class so I ought to be able to catch all and any specific exceptions if I say: Catch InvalidPremiumException

Comment: No its not like that. Let me ask you one thing: is InvalidCastException the same as or a child of InvalidPremiumException? No it is not. The Catch block will only handle those exceptions which are either of the same type or one of its children's type. That is why your custom exception is handled in the second block

Comment: Ah, ok thanks.

So, how could I add my custom exception into the .net Exception namespace in such a way that I could make it, for example a child of InvalidCastException ??

Comment: One obvious example is that you inherit your custom exception from InvalidCastException but I don't think this is what you actually want. You need to understand the concept of custom exception. These are thrown to cater specific scenario. Eg from you data access layer you can throw different custom exceptions so that the business layer can handle them and perform specific tasks. What exactly is your target that you want to achieve?